# Remote dockerised spring boot application registration in Netflix eureka service discovery server on another host

Tags: docker, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix

We hosted Netflix Eureka service discovery server and API gateway on one host machine, and have a dockerized spring boot service on another host machine When we register that service into Eureka service discovery server it takes containers IP address. So when we call that service as expected that service was not found. So whats the best practice while registering the remote docker service into service discovery server.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use an environment variable in order to set the host machine IP.

Assuming that you're using a *.yml file as your service configuration file where you will be able to set something like this:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    ipAddress: "${HOST}"
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://<eureka-host>:<eureka-port>/eureka/
```

So then you can inject the host IP as en environment variable while ruining the docker container with your service:

```
docker container run -e HOST=host_ip IMAGE_NAME
```